# What are some ways of generating a demo link for each pull request to a Single Page App?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-page-application, circleci

Today, for staging and production, we are just deploying to an AWS S3 bucket and using a Cloudfront distribution to host our SPA. We use a circle-ci pipeline to build, test and deploy. This works great for our overall build process and continuous integration. What we are trying to solve now is, when multiple developers make a PR to our SPA, we'd like to deploy that code and generate a new url based on the branch to allow QA to test the code.

[One hosted solution I found was this.](https://blog.fossasia.org/auto-deployment-of-pull-requests-on-susper-using-surge-technology/) Has anyone tried to set up their own solution to this using a server and some nginx config? Is there a best practice already out there for this?

[The main angular repo does this today.](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/26795) I'm not sure what they are using to build the `ngbuilds.io` deployments. What have you or your company done to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking a little deeper I was able to find the Angular teams documentation on how they are accomplishing this for themselves:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a01acec7febf30bdedd7fad2b6c2187886b3e9c0/aio/aio-builds-setup/docs/overview--general.md

Comment: Blog post explaining this in more detail: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19012923